# Does Meteor use SockJS as it's main browser-server communications mechanism?

Tags: websocket, long-polling, meteor

I noticed the Meteor stream package here contains SockJS:
https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/master/packages/stream

Based on some commit messages, I'g guess Meteor use SockJS polling as it's main browser-server communications mechanism. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it.  But it doesn't use websockets or streaming as commented in the code right now:

```
self.socket = new SockJS(self.url, undefined, { debug: false, protocols_whitelist: [        
    **// only allow polling protocols. no websockets or streaming.        
    // streaming makes safari spin, and websockets hurt chrome.**        
    'xdr-polling', 'xhr-polling', 'iframe-xhr-polling', 'jsonp-polling'      ]});
```

Comment: Too bad browsers aren't ready for [WebSocket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket#Browser_support).  Looks like we're waiting for Safari, Opera and IE 10 which will be out soon. WebSocket should be the default and iframe the polyfill.

Comment: Websockets should be enabled in current dev meteor, see: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/pull/69

Comment: To other googlers, you can check the status here: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/stream/stream_client.js by searching "new SockJS"

FTR, It's still the same as the above

Comment: As a followup, adding 'websocket' to that list enables websockets use.  This lowers latency a _ton_ but makes it a bit less admissible to other browsers as mentioned in the other comments.

For you lazy c/p monkeys:
self.socket = new SockJS(self.url, undefined, { debug: false, protocols_whitelist: [ 'websocket', 'xdr-polling', 'xhr-polling', 'iframe-xhr-polling', 'jsonp-polling'  ]});

Comment: @DevinGRhode: The URL to `stream_client.js` has changed to https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/livedata/stream_client_sockjs.js#L143 ; update comment?